# How To Use Remote Default Gateway in Remote Office over Site-To-Site VPN Connection

Tags: remote-access

We have a site-to-site vpn connection between our office in United States and Canada.

From the Canada office, we'd like to send our http requests through the site-to-site and utilize the default gateway from the United States office.

Is it as simple as adding a static route on our workstation?

Comment: If it's just http traffic, you'd need more than just a route. You might need a proxy server or some kind of route map on your router.

Answer (score 0):

First - avoid setting static routes on a workstation, especially if we are talking more than one workstation.

VPN connection details?  routers or firewalls or hybrid?  What kind?  Route based VPN or policy based?

With a hybrid you can setup rules that would say http traffic outbound gets tunneled through the VPN connection.  Then the US office side would then NAT the traffic out its internet interface, get the response, and then tunnel it back.

Or a simpler approach on the same lines would be to set the default route to go across the VPN connection to the US, and then all traffic would be "dealt with" at the US side regardless of type of traffic.

We've done this with locations that only had an MPLS link back to HQ.  We would route internet traffic for them.

Comment: It's an ipsec site-to-site vpn connection between a Cisco RV084 appliance and some kind of Sonicwall appliance.